# Debian Squeeze not detecting any hardware after Gnome 3.8 upgrade

Tags: debian, gnome3, hardware, networkmanager, firmware

So, somehow I accidentally upgraded to Gnome 3.8 (Don't ask me how, I have no idea).  And after a reboot, none of my peripheral devices or interfaces are working.  The built in mouse and keyboard do not respond and I have to unplug and replug them before I get any response.  Additionally, my realtek ethernet controller is not visible in the network settings window, even though it is listed in /etc/network/interfaces.  Also, when using the debian install disk for recovery, all hardware is detected without a problem.

I've searched for an answer for days but I've come up short, and I unfortunately don't know enough about Linux to do much more than examine things.  Any help you could provide with be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a partial/incomplete `dist-upgrade` that has left the kernel and kernel-modules out-of-sync.  Look at the output of `uname -a` (`uname -r` for just the kernel rev) and the modules in /lib/modules/`$(uname -r)`  `lsmod` should show various modules are loaded. `dmesg` might show why they aren't loading.

An interface won't show in NM if it's not actually there -- eth0 won't show if there's no driver loaded for it. Or there could be miscommumication among the millions of behind-the-scenes bits of NM and the rest of the gnome desktop.